# Fast integration technique in matlab?

Tags: matlab, calculus

So I have the following function that I need to code:

Lm = 1/d Integral[exp(-i(a(x)t+mKx)) dx (from 0 to d)

What I have right now is:

```
L = (1/period) * int(exp(- 1i*(ax*t+(m*K*x))),x,0,period);
subs(L,[t,m],[beta0,tt]);
```

Where everything is symbolic.  This takes a very long time if ax is anything challenging (sin(x)). So I would like to figure out a way to simplify this.  I have an array a_x(xi) and I have been referred by colleagues to look into the `quad` function, but so far I am not sure how to use that.

thanks

Comment: So `ax` is a symbolic function (`symfun`)?

Comment: Yes it is, it varies based on what I need

Answer (score 1):

If your integrand doesn't change (variables not a function of `x`) then I see no reason why you couldn't take the output of the symbolic integration and use it numerically without performing the integration:

```
kmp = K.*m.*period/2
L = exp(-1i*(ax.*t+kmp)).*sin(kmp)./kmp
```

Otherwise, yes, you should look into Matlab's [quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) [integration methods](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/integral.html) – they work vary similary to `sym/int`, but are for numerical values and functions. In newer versions of Matab try [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) or use [`quadgk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html). Something like this:

```
fun = @(x)exp(-1i*(ax*t+(m*K*x)));
L = (1/period)*integral(fun,0,period);
```

Note that for highly oscillatory functions, most quadrature methods have difficulty. You should check that your results are actually correct in such cases. If Matlab's built-in quadrature routines have trouble, you could look into [Levin integration](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23972-chebfun/content/chebfun/examples/quad/LevinIntegrate.m) schemes or maybe [this](http://www.unavarra.es/personal/victor_dominguez/clenshawcurtisrule/).